# Is there a site to solve tsumego online?

Tags: go, tsumego

I'd like to solve tsumego online, not having to install a program or app locally. Are there any sites that allow this? How about for smartphones?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### GoProblems

http://www.goproblems.com/

The traditional problem site. Has many user contributed problems. Personally I'm not too fond of it, since the problems often vary in style getting me out of the problem solving flow.

Comment: +1 - Goproblems is a useful site with a large number of problems, also it allows you to both filter problems by type, or follow paths of related problem sets if you want to work only tesuji, only ladder problems, etc.

Comment: There is no app for android, is there?

Comment: There's SmartGo for the iPad/iPhone, but none that I know of for Android.  If there is enough demand SmartGo might be willing to do a port there.

Comment: I would love to see SmartGo ported to Android.  But in the meantime there is a good set of go problems on the Android market called "Magic Baduk Go".

Comment: While I do appreciate the efforts and concept of the website. The way problems are selected and presented is too chaotic for me. When solving problems in books there is a consistency in the problems that lacks on this website. For me this ruins it.

Answer (score 4):

### GoChild

http://gochild2009.appspot.com/

Currently my favorite. Has several large collections of problems. I like it for mass solving relatively simple problem.

First you need to login with a google account. Then choose a collection on the right. And finally you need to switch to the Question or Progress tab on the right to solve problems.

Comment: maybe better split it in 2 answers?

Comment: I feel stupid, I can't seem to figure out how that site works. How do I actually attempt to solve something? Do I have to log in first?

Comment: You do seem to have to log in first, that is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite: http://www.hitachi.co.jp/Sp/tsumego/index-e.html - It's especially great for anyone between mid-SDK and dan level.

Answer (score 1):

### GoGrinder

There is a cheap app for PC and mobile called [GoGrinder](http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoGrinder). ([see also](http://gogrinder.com))

From my experience as well as what I heard from others it's a useful piece of software at a very reasonable price.